# oracle on update cascade on same table

Tags: oracle, triggers, foreign-keys, parent-child, cascade

```
ID -name -         parent     act
1   computer            1       E
2   chemicals           2       E
3   furniture           3       E
4   CPUs                1       E
5   Laptops             1       E
6   Webcams             1       E
7   Hotel Furniture     3       E
8   Home Furniture      3       E
```

I have a table above. ID and parent delete cascade connected with each other. I act when I change the column if this top category H would like to have all of the following.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CASCADE_ABC_UPD
BEFORE UPDATE
OF ID ON MY_TABLE_NAME
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 UPDATE MY_TABLE_NAME SET act=:NEW.act WHERE  PARENT=:OLD.ID;
END ;
```

I first example of the ID value of the line 'act' value 'H' did. Then I want to. The parent value is equal to one of the lines 'act' value at 'H' get.

```
ID 1,2,3 is main category. 4,5,6,7,8 is sub category. 

computer  main category             act='E'   
computer  > CPUs  sub category      act='E'        
computer  > Laptops  sub category   act='E'                  
computer  > Webcams  sub category   act='E'
```

now: i want to update that computer  main category

UPDATE MY_TABLE_NAME SET act='H' WHERE  ID=1;

trigger is tripped (No error but don't working)

```
 BEGIN
     UPDATE MY_TABLE_NAME SET act=:NEW.act WHERE  PARENT=:OLD.ID;
    END ;
```

after

```
computer  main category             act='H'   
computer  > CPUs  sub category      act='E'        
computer  > Laptops  sub category   act='E'                  
computer  > Webcams  sub category   act='E'
```

desirable that the:

```
computer  main category             act='H'   
computer  > CPUs  sub category      act='H'        
computer  > Laptops  sub category   act='H'                  
computer  > Webcams  sub category   act='H'
```

I've updated the main category, sub-category, but are still active. main categories, sub-categories of passive passive if you want to get all. Is it possible to make it as cascade update

Comment: Hard to understand what you are asking!

Comment: ID 1,2,3 is main category. 4,5,6,7,8 is sub category for 1. i want to update table_name set act=h where id=1; no problem... but sub category(4,5,6,7,8) is act='E'... i dont want it...

Comment: If somebody says they don't understand your question, simply repeating  exactly what you've already typed doesn't help.  You need to *edit your question* to make it clearer.  As easy way to do that would be to show how you want the sample data to look at the end of the transaction.

Comment: Also, you need to explain what you mean by `sub-category`, as it seems like a concept which isn't supported by the data model you've posted here.

Comment: dosn't work this sql:UPDATE MY_TABLE_NAME SET act=:NEW.act WHERE  PARENT=:OLD.ID;